# Normalizar valores, o que é que me está a escapar?

Tags: python, normalização

os R´s são matrizes do tipo

```
[120.0, 77.34999999999998, 12.639999999999974, 39.270000000000074, 62.879999999999846, 54.549999999999656, 2.400000000000313, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 70.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 62.879999999999846, 54.549999999999656, 2.400000000000313, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.349999999999995, 12.639999999999974, 39.270000000000074, 62.879999999999846, 54.549999999999656, 2.400000000000313, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

eu com este comando crio uma nova matriz formada com os máximos valores das matrizes R...

```
input: matriz=np.array([[R], [R1], [R2], [R3], [R4], [R5], [R6]])
       Probabilidades=np.max(matriz, axis=0)
output:[[150.    77.35  12.64  39.27  62.88  54.55   2.4   50.    50.    50.
   50.    50.    50.    50.    70.    70.     0.     0.     0.    62.88
   54.55   2.4   50.     0.     0.     0.     7.35  12.64  89.27  62.88
   54.55   2.4   50.    50.    50.    50.    50.     0.    50.  ]]
```

Quero agora normalizar/scale isto, para que o valor máximo seja **100** (*ou 1*) e não **150**.

```
input: from sklearn import preprocessing
       import numpy as np

       matriz=np.array([[R], [R1], [R2], [R3], [R4], [R5], [R6]])
       Probabilidades=np.max(matriz, axis=0)
       matriz1 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
       ProbNormalizada= matriz1.fit_transform(Probabilidades)
       print(ProbNormalizada)
```

Comment: quano tem em: matriz=np.array([[R], [R1], [R2], [R3], [R4], [R5], [R6]]), os R´s são matrizes do tipo

Comment: [120.0, 77.34999999999998, 12.639999999999974, 39.270000000000074, 62.879999999999846, 54.549999999999656, 2.400000000000313, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 70.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 62.879999999999846, 54.549999999999656, 2.400000000000313, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.349999999999995, 12.639999999999974, 39.270000000000074, 62.879999999999846, 54.549999999999656, 2.400000000000313, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0]

Comment: e eu com o comando quero uma nova matriz formada com os máximos valores das matrizes R...

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza se o termo para o que vc quer seja "Normalizar", pelos termos usados na documentção do `sklearn` acredito que o termo mais adequado seria `scale` (ou algo parecido), veja o exemplo:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

output = np.array([150.0, 77.35, 12.64, 39.27, 62.88, 54.55, 2.4, 50., 50., 50., 
                   50., 50., 50., 50., 70., 70., 0., 0., 0., 62.88, 54.55, 2.4,
                   50., 0., 0., 0., 7.35, 12.64, 89.27, 62.88, 54.55, 2.4, 50.,
                   50., 50., 50., 50., 0., 50.])    

output2 = minmax_scale(output.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(len(output))
print(output2)
```

Saída:

```
[1.         0.51566667 0.08426667 0.2618     0.4192     0.36366667
 0.016      0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333
 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.46666667 0.46666667 0.         0.
 0.         0.4192     0.36366667 0.016      0.33333333 0.
 0.         0.         0.049      0.08426667 0.59513333 0.4192
 0.36366667 0.016      0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333
 0.33333333 0.         0.33333333]
```

Se quiser saber como são feitos os calculos [consulte esse link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale).